# VS Code extension API: Is it possible to extend/enhance the existing file explorer?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have an idea of a plugin that would require modifying the VS Code file explorer visually. Is there any way to access the view through the extension API?

I'm aware that there is an API for adding new tree views (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points#_contributesviews) but I've found no mention of being able to customize the existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from vscode in [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9963) :

> There are no plans to give access to the dom for various reasons explained here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/our-approach

...

> we do not provide direct access to the underlying UI DOM to extension writers.
>
> The approach to run the extensions isolated in a separate process allows VS Code to strictly control the API exposed to extenders. See the Extensibility API Overview for details on the current API.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to access the view through the extension API?

No. The extensions run in their own process and do not have direct access to the UI dom.